# Crystal Reports Syntax for AND

Tags: crystal-reports, formula-editor

I am trying to make a formula so that if the Comments field contains both the terms "special market" **AND** "promo" regardless of order or spacing then the field will return 9. The formula below returns 9 if either "special market" **OR** "promo" appears. What syntax do I use to achieve my goal?

```
if{@Comments} like ["*special market*",  "*promo*"]  then "9"
```

Regards,

Richie P

Comment: 1000 views and not a single upvote. Jeez.

Answer (score 3):

You need to test separately:

```
if ({@Comments} like "*special market*") and 
   ({@Comments} like "*promo*")  then "9"
```